# free hosting to demo a static webpage for SO question?

Tags: discussion, hosting, web-hosting

I have a little html issue and wanted to post the page on the web. Are there any free hosting services I can use for this? The page has static content so I don't need a service which supports databases or any server languages. The url should be off the provider's domain name (not mine) and quick and easy to set up. I don't care if they put ads. SO recommends an image hosting provider. Looking for similar option for a whole page.

Comment: it's asking where to host resources for a SO question, so it might make for a nice faq entry on meta, don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

try [**jsbin**](http://jsbin.com)

Taken from the [About](http://jsbin.com/about) page

> JS Bin is a webapp specifically
>   designed to help JavaScript and CSS
>   folk test snippets of code, within
>   some context, and debug the code
>   collaboratively.
>
> JS Bin allows you to edit and test
>   JavaScript and HTML (reloading the URL
>   also maintains the state of your code
>   - new tabs doesn't). Once you're happy you can save, and send the URL to a
>   peer for review or help. They can then
>   make further changes saving anew if
>   required.
>
> The original idea spawned from a
>   conversation with another developer in
>   trying to help him debug an Ajax
>   issue. The original aim was to build
>   it using Google's app engine, but in
>   the end, it was John Resig's Learning
>   app that inspired me to build the
>   whole solution in JavaScript with
>   liberal dashes of jQuery and a tiny
>   bit of LAMP for the saving process.
>
> It took me the best part of 4 hours to
>   develop - so if it's shaky around the
>   edges, let me know!
>
> This webapp was built by Remy Sharp
>   (@rem) of Left Logic. Please get in
>   touch if you're interested in working
>   with me.

Page will remain hosted until the page has not been viewed for 3 months

Comment: Nice! I'll have to remember that one.

Answer (score 0):

It's not *quite* free, but [nearlyfreespeech.net](https://www.nearlyfreespeech.net/) is pay-by-use, and I believe they give you some free credit for signing up.

Answer (score 0):

To host some code, you can try [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or [pastie](http://pastie.org/) *(there must be plenty of those)*

They won't host your **page**, but, at least, they'll allow you to distribute the source-code that constitutes it.

BTW : what do you mean by "page" ? Only some HTML file ? On HTML+JS+CSS+Images and all that stuff ?

Comment: I need hosting so I can provide a link.
Page = html + css + images + js